# How to remove a double quotes before and after the square bracket from the whole json output

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json

Find below my json output

```
[
    {
        "tname": "yyyy",
        "first_name": "xxx",
        "last_name": "yyyy",
        "pri": "pub",
        "skills": "[{\"description\": \"1 YEAR\", \"Name\": \"Programming\", \"Competence\": \"PHP\"}, {\"description\": \"2 YEAR\", \"Name\": \"Programming\", \"Competence\": \"JAVA\"}]",
        "contact_phone": "875433333333",
        "experience_years": 2,
        "experience": "[{\"description\": \"deve\", \"endYear\": \"2014-07-08\", \"designation\": \"developer\", \"startYear\": \"2013-03-12\", \"companyName\": \"xxx\"}, {\"description\": \"dev\", \"endYear\": \"2015-02-03\", \"designation\": \"developer\", \"startYear\": \"2014-02-09\", \"companyName\": \"yyy\"}]",
        "accomplishments": "[{\"Institution\": \"EVR COLLG\", \"description\": \"EVT\", \"Name\": \"xxx\", \"Year\": \"2013-04-02\"}, {\"Institution\": \"ASV COLLG\", \"description\": \"ASV\", \"Name\": \"YYY\", \"Year\": \"2014-02-02\"}]",
        "contact_email": "xx@gmail.com",
        "education_gist": [
            "SSLC",
            "HSC",
            "UG",
            "PG"
        ],
        "address": " \r\n \r\n \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tno:7, XXX XX, YYYY- 560543\t\r\n \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t \r\n ",
        "about_me": " \r\n I am xx from XXX, i am a WWW DDD.\r\n \r\n \r\n\r\n ",
        "education": "[{\"description\": \"school first\", \"startYear\": \"2004-02-02\", \"grade\": \"95\", \"collegeName\": \"govt high school\", \"endYear\": \"2004-01-04\", \"qualification\": \"SSLC\"}, {\"description\": \"class first\", \"startYear\": \"2006-01-01\", \"grade\": \"90\", \"collegeName\": \"gov boy hr school\", \"endYear\": \"2006-12-04\", \"qualification\": \"HSC\"}, {\"description\": \"department first\", \"startYear\": \"2012-06-09\", \"grade\": \"94\", \"collegeName\": \"B.Sc\", \"endYear\": \"2015-07-02\", \"qualification\": \"UG\"}, {\"description\": \"GOLD MEDAL\", \"startYear\": \"2015-07-09\", \"grade\": \"9.8\", \"collegeName\": \"MCA\", \"endYear\": \"2015-07-25\", \"qualification\": \"PG\"}]",
        "user_name": "xx",
        "projects": "[{\"Company\": \"XXX\", \"endYear\": \"2015-08-14\", \"Name\": \"XYZ PROJECT\", \"startYear\": \"2015-07-29\", \"description\": \"DEVELOPER\"}, {\"Company\": \"YYYY\", \"endYear\": \"2015-07-31\", \"Name\": \"ABC PROJECT\", \"startYear\": \"2015-07-01\", \"description\": \"DESIGNER\"}]"
    }
]
```

And i want to remove the (") double quotes before "[ and after ]" the square brackets

```
"skills": "[{\"description\": \"1 YEAR\", \"Name\": \"Programming\", \"Competence\": \"PHP\"}, {\"description\": \"2 YEAR\", \"Name\": \"Programming\", \"Competence\": \"JAVA\"}]",
```

"skills":

> "[

and \"JAVA\"}

> ]"

,

I wanted the solution using jquery or javascript, don't want in PHP, Give me the solution if any one knows. Thanks in advance

Comment: Then it becomes illegal JSON, and therefore no longer JSON. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Parse the JSON, pick out the parts you want, then serialize it again.

Answer (score 3):

Say your data is called `data`

```
data[0].skills = JSON.parse(data[0].skills);
// etc...
```

If you want to keep the data internal to the array as strings then:

```
data[0].skills = JSON.parse(data[0].skills).map(function(obj) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj);
});
```

And to do it all programmatically

```
data.forEach(function(obj){
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj.key === "string" && obj.key[1] === "[") {
            obj[key] = JSON.parse(obj[key]).map(function(inArray) {
                return JSON.stringify(inArray);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Of course!  If I provided the best answer would you mark me as correct as well?

Answer (score 2):

This is what you should do, simple regex substitute

```js
jsonData = '"["smt": "smtelse" ]"'; 

jsonData = jsonData.replace(/"\[/g, '[');
jsonData = jsonData.replace(/\]"/g, ']');
```